# newsletter_subscriber always null

Tags: newsletter

I new on Magento and as you can guess I have a question.
I Have magento community 1.8, and I saw that my table 
'newsletter_subscriber' field change_status_at is always null.

I don't know where to look to properly feed this field.
some help will be apreciate.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to fill in this field?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is never used. The function to set this value would be something like `setChangeStatusAt` but I cannot find a call to this in Magento 1.6 or upwards. Maybe it is an old column that has never been removed from Magento but is no longer used.

The only place I can find the getter function `getStatusChangedDate` called is in the admin grid up that also appears not to be being used apart from adding a column to the grid when there is a changed date.